# outlook 2016 how to disable the new "Newest on top" feature

Tags: sorting, microsoft-outlook-2016, layout

As part of the latest updates to Office/Outlook 2016, suddenly the section above the messages list got "weird" in its layout.
The best way to understand what I'm trying to describe here is to look at the images below...

What it used to look like:

[image]

And what it looks like now:

[image]

They added a section for quick sorting the list of messages by the selected field (here - "By Date" + the arrow for the direction of the sort).

I'm looking for a way to disable this and get the original look and layout back.

UPDATE:

Basically, this is what I would like to remove form display/layout:

[image]

In hope that by removing that somehow, the layout will go back to what it was (like in the first screenshot image above)

UPDATE:

I believe it was indeed a bug after all, because after an update to Office, this issue disappeared and the original view has been restored.

Comment: Is this Office 365 or a non-365 install?

Comment: I'm afraid it's hard-coded and no option available to disable/remove it.

Answer (score -1):

This [arrangement feature](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Change-how-the-Message-List-is-arranged-f3646496-efe0-4102-bf22-5cf66abd7e76) was always there. Now they are explicitly showing a header item to configure.

You can click on that & change the way you want. You can edit the view settings to change. If you are concerned about the layout of columns like showing categories, flag, etc still can right click on the header row to add/remove.

[image]

I don’t remember seeing an option to reset the view to classic. Pls read the [customize view topics](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Customize-dba4d238-f29f-4800-b0cb-504359469d9d#ID0EAABAAA=Customize_view) to explore more.

Comment: Please take another look at the images I've attached to my original question above... I'm not talking about the arrangement of the columns, but what's above these columns, where the search bar appears and so on... This is the difference I'm referring to, between what was the layout there until recently, and how it looks now, after the latest updates...